# Language menu is gone for new references in microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, language, bibliography

I work with a Dutch version of MS-Word. When I add a reference in the bibliography normally there is a pull down menu with languages. On default this is on Dutch, so I have to select English to show the reference in the right way in my English thesis. For example in between two authors 'and' will be placed in stead of 'en'.

However this morning, suddenly the menu was gone :O ~~ see example image in the link...

I tried restarting Word and also check if the same holds for a new document in Word. Restart didn't fix the problem and also in a new document the problem occurs.

Can someone help me?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only see the Language dropdown (or the Taal dropdown in the Dutch language interface) if more than one *editing* language has been set up. It sounds as if you might have lost one of the Editing languages.

Before trying to add an editing language, I recommend that you make a backup of your normal.dotm template, as Word may want to replace it.

In recent versions of Word you can go to File->Options->Language (Bestand->Opties->Taal in the Dutch version) to add an editing language. Word will probably tell you to close all Office programs before you will see the change. In Word 2007 I think the equivalent language setup was in a separate program that you can probably find by clicking the Start button and looking for the Microsoft Office programs folder.

Comment: Good to mention maybe... The references that were already in the list do still have the pull down menu. Will your solution still be valid?
Furthermore I have the Office 365 and I updated it somewhere during the lost couple of months... And the last month or so I didn't made new references

Comment: "Will your solution still be valid?" You can only try it and see.

Comment: Only one way to find out... IT WORKED! Thanx a lot!